# Run CLI with arguments as params to a main method

Tags: java, command-line-interface

I have written a CLIInterface in java that takes the necessary flags from the user as a String[].

Here is some sample code:

```
public static void call(String[] args)
{
    try
    {
        Map<String, Object> cliOptions = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; ++i) {

            // override the db directory
            if (args[i].equals("--help")) {

                printHelp();
                System.exit(1);
            }
            ..........
}
```

I know that you can invoke the method in the command line using something like this:

java -Dexec.mainClass=org.bitcoinj.examples.ForwardingService -Dexec.args=""

but I want to be able to use it like a CLI and have something like this:

**ethj --help whereby --help would be args[0] and then from there I could handle it in the call method.**

How would one go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way is to write a *starter script* `ethj` for your operation system passing the arguments to the java executable.

---

btw:

you don't need the `-Dexec.args=""` form, just list the parameters after the main class name...